# How to Filter the data from the multiple array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the data from multiple array of objects like that name key according.
I have a multiple array of object. Something like:

```
data = [
  {
    state: 'saass',
    name: 'Saass',
    type: 'sub',
    icon: 'dashboard',
    active: true,
    children: [
       { state: 'executive', name: 'Executive Dashboard', type: 'link' },
       { state: 'sales', name: 'Sales Dashboard', type: 'link' },
       { state: 'marketing',name: 'Marketing Dashboard', type: 'link' },
       { state: 'support', name: 'Support Dashboard', type: 'link' },
       { state: 'course', name: 'Course Detail', type: 'sub_child', children: [
         { state: 'executive', name: 'Executive Dashboard', type: 'link' },
         { state: 'marketing', name: 'Marketing Dashboard', type: 'link'}
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   state: 'file-manager',
   name: 'File Manager',
   type: 'sub',
   icon: 'dashboard',
   active: false,
   children: [
     { state: 'authentication', name: 'Authentication', type: 'link'},
     { state: 'database', name: 'Database', type: 'link'},
     { state: 'storage', name: 'Storage', type: 'link'}
   ]
 }
];
```

In the input field I want to type the text. That text checks the data array of objects and that its according value will be show.

I need to filter the array, remove the other field that does not contain a text.

Suppose I want to search a text 's' then which name content contains the 's' keyword that keyword will be showing. For reference:
    https://www.gotbootstrap.com/themes/smartadmin/4.0.2/intel_analytics_dashboard.html

Comment: please show an example you tried ?

Comment: searchMenu(event){
  var searchValue;
  this.searchKeyword =this.data.filter(function(list){
   return list.name.toLowerCase().includes(event);
  })
  console.log(this.searchKeyword);
 }

Comment: so you want to filter data from that object if you search for keyword,example search for 's' you want object' name: 'Saass' right ?

Comment: yes, but I want to filter the data from the multiple array of object like if search for 's' then I want 'saass' , 'Sales Dashboard',''Support Dashboard'" like all in which word s keyword appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could help you

```
function filterSearch(data,val) {
    let term =val.toLowerCase()
    var matches = [];
    if (!Array.isArray(data)) return matches;

    data.forEach(function(i) {
        if (i.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
            matches.push(i);
        } else {
            let childResults = filterSearch(i.children, term);
            if (childResults.length)
                matches.push(Object.assign({}, i, { children: childResults }));
        }
    })

    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but Its not work properly because I want to filter a from  multiple array of objects Now When I search the "dashboard" it show the blank array.

Comment: oh you wanted to search children also ?

Comment: yes, check this refernce in which menu list according I need it.https://www.gotbootstrap.com/themes/smartadmin/4.0.2/intel_analytics_dashboard.html